# Using chisquared to measure the goodness-of-fit of a MLE normal

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, optimization, chi-squared-test

disclaimer: this is part of an assignment.

I am trying to compare the accuracy of different non-analytic minimisation methods for maximum likelihood estimation.

As a simple example, where we have an analytical solution, let's say that we want to test minimisation using the univariate Gaussian likelihood.

1. Generate a sample of normally distributed values, $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$.
2. Analytically determine $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the mean and variance of the sample. These will be the benchmark values.
   [image: histogram of sample]

Here you can see a normalised histogram of the sampled values, as well as the pdf of the normal fitted on the analytical parameters.

3. Minimise $-\ln \mathcal{L}(\mu, \sigma | x)$ to get $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$.
4. Generate probabilities using the univariate Gaussian pdf $Y \sim N(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma})$.
5. Compare $X$ and $Y$ using the $\chi^{2}$ goodness-of-fit test.

But this is where I am stuck, for my $X$ is a (n, 1) array of a random sample of points, and my $Y$ is the probabilities of points along a specific interval.

Where exactly am I going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question was not appropriately defined.

Rather, the $\chi^{2}$ goodness-of-fit here is the component of the log likelihood $-\mathcal{L}(\mu, \sigma| x)$ involving $\mu$,

$$\chi^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i} - \mu )^{2}$$

where $\mu$ is the model to be tested. $\mu$ here need not be a constant, but rather a *model* or function of some parameters $\theta$, which are in fact the parameters to optimise for.